# How do I pass an overloaded method with a parameter?

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm writing a program where the user enter specs of a PC, and then I print out those specs. I have two classes, the main class (PCSpecsDriver), and the class that gets the input (PCSpecsClass).

In the PCSpecsClass, I had an overloaded method named "type", which basically asked the user what type of laptop or desktop they would like. They both had different parameters. However, when I tried to call the method in the driver class, it pointed at the parameter and gave me this error: "cannot find symbol".

I know this might be an easy answer but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you so much! Here is my code:

```
public class PCSpecsDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;
        PCSpecsClass computer = new PCSpecsClass();

        do { 
              System.out.println("What kind of PC would you like to build(Laptop/Desktop)?"); 
              String response = kb.next();

              switch (response.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "desktop": 
                          computer.type(desktopResponse);
                          break;

                    case "laptop":
                          computer.type(laptopResponse);

                    default:
                          System.out.println("Not a valid response!");

              }

              System.out.println("Would you like to build another?");
              answer = kb.next();

        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
  }




public class PCSpecsClass {


  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


  String laptopResponse;
  int desktopResponse; 

  public int type(int desktopResponse) {
        System.out.println("Type: Input 1 for laptop, 2 for notebook, 3 for tablet");
        return desktopResponse = kb.nextInt();
  }

  public String type(String laptopResponse) {
        System.out.println("Size: Input 1 for mini, 2 for medium, 3 for large");
        return laptopResponse = kb.nextLine();
  }
```

Comment: The code you provided cannot compile. Please provide relevant code to analyze.

Comment: `computer.desktopType(desktopResponse);` Here's your problem. The `PCSpecsClass` class doesn't have a `desktopType` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza They seem to be asking why it doesn't compile. If it compiled, they wouldn't be here.

Comment: @mypetlion there's no variable called `desktopResponse`, neither `laptopResponse`. If these are the case, then it's not worth the time to review it and the question should be closed as "this person does not even review what the IDE says about the code".

Comment: @mypetlion sorry, I just realized my mistake. I changed both method names to "type" and edited my post accordingly. However, the code still does not compile :/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry, my mistake. I edited the code in the post.

Comment: Here, inside the `switch` in `main` method: `computer.type(desktopResponse);`. What is `desktopResponse`? Such variable has not been defined yet. That raises a compiler error and the IDE provides that message clearly for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you pass variables/references into a method. When you call computer.type() in the switch case, you are trying to feed it references that don't exist in the `PCSpecsDriver` class. `desktopResponse` and `laptopResponse` refer to values that don't exist. For starters, revisit a Java (EDIT: Doesn't even have to be Java, scope is a basic (not the language) programming concept) tutorial and see the difference between local and global scope. Then, rethink the design of this PCSpecs program. Also, **Read the error messages in your IDE.** If you had done that, you wouldn't be here.